# How to get rid of false dependencies in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

It appears that when using gerrit, by default all changes depend on the previous one. I do not branch for new changes, I simply work off the master branch and then push the commited changes to a remote origin/master. A dependency is created every time even if the two commits have nothing to do with each other.

I've run into a few issues which makes me think that I am not using git correctly in combination with gerrit.

What should happen differently in my git/gerrit workflow for every commit to not be dependent on the previous commit? I've also tried creating a new branch for the change:

```
> git pull origin master
> git checkout -b new_branch
> #make a change
> git add -A
> git commit #with gerrit's commit hook in .git/hooks
> git push origin <sha1>:refs/for/master
```

This works, but gerrit still reports a dependency on the previously commited item.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're asking. What do you mean by "a dependency?"

Comment: Gerrit shows what issues are dependent on / a dependency of. For example, I check in issue #1 to gerrit, and then check in a completely different #2 that doesn't even touch the same file. Gerrit reports that #2 is dependent on #1. This seems wrong.

Comment: using a git rebase -i and removing the dependencies yourself can also be a way to get rid of dependencies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what `Gerrit` means by dependencies - A commit which is on top of another commit.  If both are in review, the newer one depends on the older one.

If you don't want them to depend on each other, don't create the commits on top of each other.  Create one commit, then make a new branch based on master for your next commit

`(git checkout origin/master -b NEW_BRANCH_NAME)`.

When you push the second commit up for review, it's parent will already be published and it won't depend on anything.

Comment: I've seen mention of branching for each code change... but as in my edited question, this still seems to produce the same results. Any more ideas?

Comment: The command you are using to create a branch (git checkout -b new_branch) makes the new branch on top of the current commit.  You want to reset back to what the server views as the current commit - so specify that in the checkout command.  git checkout *origin/master* -b new_branch.

Comment: @Brad Your comment makes sense. I just wanted to point out that the documentation for git-checkout has the starting point as the last parameter:  
    git checkout [-q] [-f] [-m] [[-b|-B|--orphan] <new_branch>] [<start_point>]  
  
So your example would be:  
    git checkout -b new_branch _origin/master_

Comment: Hey @Plazgoth, the -b <new_branch> is a flag, just like -f, -q, and <start_point>.  The order of these flags doesn't matter so the example above works just fine - try it out if you don't believe me :)

Comment: I know it works. It just seems less common to put the starting point before the flags.

Answer (score 0):

I've been taught to get around this by doing `git reset --hard HEAD~1` after each `git push`.

Comment: Would you like to comment on why you think this is wrong, to perhaps avoid perpetuating misinformation and better inform me?

Comment: The problem with this approach that you get rid of the commit completely after you push. Say, you have iterative reviews on the gerrit, you may want to change the previous commit based on the comments. This approach would require you to cherry pick the change again from gerrit to be able to work on it. 

I find this difficult in cases where I branch out to do a big fix and have setup running on that code. If I want to push a minor indpendent fix on the same code line, I don't want to lose the major commit for this minor fix as that might attract more changes based on reviews.

Comment: Not a problem at all. All commits that have been pushed are stored on the server and locally. You work on one, push it, then you work on another. When you get feedback on one and want to modify it again, you just check it out to work on it. Putting a branch name on it is a convenience, nothing more.

Comment: When I work in a big repo (which takes long to checkout, and even has various submodules), I use several [worktrees](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-worktree.html) rather than branches. They all use detached heads, and I just delete the directories when I'm done. With branches I find that the namespace gets pretty cluttered. With worktrees, they are all in front of me and I use normal filesystem tools to manage them.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant to `git reset --hard HEAD~1` I use this instead:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Assuming, I'm working in `master` for a quick change.

Otherwise, working in a topic branch is much preferred.

There are many Git scripts to help manage topic branches:

- [`git-flow`](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow)
- [`git extras`](https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras)
- `git create-branch`

I'm sure there are others.

Comment: I think "git reset -- hard origin/master" is better... because above command gave error and worked after giving space in - and hard